# TCPDF - How to use GetStringWidth when text is bold

Tags: php, tcpdf, fpdf

Is there a way to use GetStringWidth on text that has  formatting? Right now if I have <b>Jarod</b>, the GetStringWidth treats the tags as if they are text to display and returns the string width including the tags. If I take them out, then the String Width returned is for non-bold text and we know that bold text is bigger than non-formatted text, so I'm trying to figure out how to measure formatted text width in TCPDF. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According [TCPDF Doc](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a8075c1f04b6fbddc957cff786c4b16d9) you can send parameters to the `GetStringWidth()` function, including font style.
In your example:

```
$text_width = $pdf->GetStringWidth("Text To Be Measured",'','B');
```

Comment: This would be much easier and I hadn't seen this before.

Answer (score 3):

Just figure this out. In TCPDF, we always use SetFont('Times','',12); where we have Font family or name, next is the '' where we can put I or B or U, etc. and then the font size. The problem with GetStringWith that I was having is that I was using the default font setting to measure my font when I needed to measure bold. To the Fix:

```
//Temporarily set the font to Bold.
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',12);

//Now measure the text that needs to be measured;

$text_width = $pdf->GetStringWidth("Text To Be Measured");

//Now reset the font back to normal so the rest of the document isn't messed up.

$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
```

I hope this helps someone else.